# Kafka .NET - get all existing records for that specific topic and then carry on listening for new ones

Tags: .net, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

In a basic Kafka .NET consumer setup like this

```
conf = new ConsumerConfig
{
            GroupId = $"{_topic}{CacheMessageConsumerSuffix}",
            BootstrapServers = Servers,
            AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetResetType.Earliest,
};


using (var c = new Consumer<string, string>(conf))
{
    c.Subscribe(_topic);

    bool consuming = true;
    c.OnError += (_, e) => consuming = !e.IsFatal;

    while (consuming)
    {
        var cr = c.Consume();
    }
}
```

That consumer will, when started, only receive new messages from a Producer. How to first get all existing records for that specific topic and then carry on listening for new ones?

Thanks

Comment: Please show your conf variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your config, add this after changing your current consumer group value (if you have one)

```
AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetResetType.Earliest
```

Refer [the README](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/README.md#basic-consumer-example)

Comment: I have added the configuration to the original post. I think maybe the issue is that the consumer group id is static, i.e. Kafka will always see it as if the messages were already received. In other words, some sort of manual reset or polling is required...or what?

Comment: The above config only applies if there was not a previously existing group id that has committed its offsets. But it isn't static, you are setting `GroupId` in the config

Comment: But the group id is the same every time. I tried adding a Guid to the groupId and it now replays all messages on startup.

Comment: You need to set it to a unique value only **once**. Having a guid will make it be different everytime... For example, set it to `consumer-group-1`, then assuming no other group was started with that name, then with the above config, it starts from the beginning. Say there are ten messages, then you consume 5, and commit and stop the consumer. Then start the app again, same group, then it gets the remaining 5. Whether of not you commit those remaining 5, you stop the app, and change the name to `consumer-group-2`. It will start from offset 0 again because a new group. Does that make sense?

Comment: + I don't know what this means - `CacheMessageConsumerSuffix`, but the value should only be "static" between consecutive runs of the application. It needs to be unique from existing groups consuming from that topic if you want to go back to the beginning. **Or**, you can download the Kafka CLI tools and use the `kafka-consumer-groups --reset` option

Comment: All of what you are saying makes sense and as I understand it, it means that if you have a service maintaining an in-memory cache of data which is sourced from Kafka, and you restart that service (and thereby wipe the internal cache) you need to start the consumer with a new ID to properly rebuild your cache from scratch. I have tried fiddling around with Assign(...) to force the consumer back to Offset 0 but I cannot get that to work...

Comment: Or you could not keep an in-memory cache at all, and use Kafka's compacted topics as a type of persistent KV-Store. Regarding the assign problem, feel free to create a new post, and accept this one if it has answered your initial question

Answer (score 0):

I think I worked out how to do it. As suggested in this blog post, http://blog.empeccableweb.com/wp/2016/11/30/manual-offsets-in-kafka-consumers-example/, you can set up an event handler to be triggered when partitions are assigned to a given consumer and then force those partitions back to offset 0. Something like this:

```
using (var consumer = new Consumer<string,string>(configuration))
{
_consumer.OnPartitionsAssigned += OnPartitionsAssigned;
_consumer.Subscribe("my-topic");
...
}

private void OnPartitionsAssigned(object sender, List<TopicPartition> assignedPartitions)
{
    // Build a new list of Topic/Partition/Offset values with offset = Beginning
    var newPartitionOffsets = new List<TopicPartitionOffset>();
    assignedPartitions.ForEach(x => newPartitionOffsets.Add(new TopicPartitionOffset(x, Offset.Beginning)));

    // Assign to consumer
    consumer.Assign(newPartitionOffsets);
}
```

Not sure if there is a more clever way but this seems to do the trick. Of course it only works if this event is only triggered immediately after a subscription is started and not during its lifetime. But even that can probably be managed.